# Alternating background colors with exp:calendar:day tag?

Tags: solspace-calendar

We have a day view (schedule) and wanted to tint the background of every-other event in the schedule. The switch variable doesn't seem to work, and there's no count variable we could discover... how would you go about this?

We're inside of the {calendar:events} loop at this point. Are we missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could just do this with CSS:

```
tr.yourclassname:nth-child(even) { background: #CCC }
```

Comment: Well duh! ... as folks use to say. I was thinking programmatically. This should work though. Thanks for shaking my brain loose.

Comment: Happy to help :)